# Unable to display menu using radio buttons in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Want to display the menu using radio buttons for each item and display them on GUI and the items to display are imported from the SQL database, so getting this error **_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-text"** when the following code is executed

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import pyodbc as pd

display = Tk()
mb = Menu(display)
menubar = tk.Menu(mb)


def gett():
    disp(conn)


def disp(conn):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT "Food Item" FROM dbo.Sheet1$')
    i = 0
    radio = IntVar()
    for row in cursor:
        menubar.add_radiobutton(text=row[0], variable=radio, value=i)
        i += 1
    menubar.add_cascade(Label="Items", menu=menubar)


conn = pd.connect(
    "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
    "Server=LAPTOP-I8FD6VJC\SQL2016;"
    "Database=Restaurant;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)
disp(conn)
```

Comment: Use `label=...` instead of `text=...` in `add_radiobutton(...)`.

Comment: Read up on [Tkinter.Menu.add-method - options](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.add-method)

Answer (score 1):

There are following issues in your code:

- `text=...` in `menubar.add_radiobutton(text=row[0], variable=radio, value=i)` should be `label=...`
- `menubar.add_cascade(Label="Items", menu=menubar)` should be `mb.add_cascade(label="Items", menu=menubar)`

Also mixing `from tkinter import *` and `import tkinter as tk` together is bad practice.  Just use the later one.